# How to open vnc viewer and login vnc with one command line

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc

I download vnc viewer from [here](https://www.realvnc.com/download/vnc/), i find it's a binary file, so **my question is** how to open vnc viewer and login vnc with one command line, for instance

```
ruby -e "puts (File.read 'path/to/my/passwd')"| ./VNC-Viewer-5.2.2-Linux-x64 --passwd
```

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). Don't [edit] your question to add the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with `vncviewer -passwd ~/.vnc/passwd localhost:5901`, ~/.vnc/passwd must be generated with `vncpasswd`